# JSON return Array instead of integer datatype after newtonsoft upgrade into version 10

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Expected result:

```
"sections": [
    {
        "sectionName": "Test Data",
        "sectionOrder": 1,
        "sectionColumn": 1 
    }
]
```

Actual Result:

```
"sections": [
    {
        "sectionName": [],
        "sectionOrder": [],
        "sectionColumn": [] 
    }
]
```

I am assuming that the newtonsoft causes the issue for the datatype.
I'm serializing a section and returning JSON like:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Serialize(testdata);
```

While debugging, it is showing integer value in the result for sectionOrder and sectionColumn but somehow the postman showing the result as empty array.
Not getting any exception in the result

postman result with empty array
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AddpS.png)

Comment: What exactly is the question? You state clearly: "_while debugging, it showing integer value in the result for sectionOrder and sectionColumn_" - that can only be interpreted as "code works properly" - but PostMan doesn't. So is this a PostMan question?

Comment: You speake of NewtonSoft and have the Json.net tag but the code use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`. And can we have the `testdata` object initialization? And `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` is now deprecated (2009) as the documentation state : _"For .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, the APIs in the System.Text.Json namespace should be used for serialization and deserialization. For earlier versions of .NET Framework, use Newtonsoft.Json."_

Comment: Ok my bad it was obsolete in feb 2009. Now it's not. But they strongly recommend to use anything else.

Comment: Can you also show the class you are serializing? Should there be values in the postman example?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am sending a request through the postman and expecting the some result.
inside the result sectionOrder and sectionColumn returned as empty after the newtonsoft upgrade.
{"sections":[{"sectionName":"Test Data","sectionOrder":1,"sectionColumn":2}]} this is a sample response contain the sectionOrder is 1 and sectionColumn is 2. but after looking into the postman it showing an empty array

Comment: @AvinashM - might you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  For instance if you are trying to serialize a `JObject` with `JavaScriptSerializer` you might get something like what you show.  Or might not, I'm not sure.  A [mcve] would make that clear.